# Having trouble with limit by definition proof

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing, epsilon-delta

Define

$f:(-1,1)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ by $f(x)=\frac{x+1}{x^2-1}$. Does $f$ have a limit at 1?

---

Well we know that $f(x)=\frac{x+1}{x^2-1}=\frac{1}{x-1}$. Thus clearly there is no limit.

By definition,

$\lim_{x\rightarrow c}f(x)$  means $ \forall N>0:\exists \delta :0<|x-c|<\delta \implies f(x)>N$.

So, my attempt/combined with answer given:

Let $\epsilon>0 \text{ and } L \in \mathbb{R}$. Then, 
$|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$, for $0<x-1<\frac{1}{L+\epsilon}$ (I don't understand this part). Thus, $L+\epsilon>\frac{1}{L+\epsilon}=f(x)$. Hence, $|f(x)-L|>\epsilon$. Therefore, it is impossible to find $\delta>0$ that fulfills the definition. Thus, $f$ does not have a limit at $x=1$.

---

Can someone perhaps show me a better way of doing this?

Comment: You gave a definition for $\lim_{x \to \infty}$ but didn't use it later. Did you mean to give the definition for $\lim_{x \to a}$?

Comment: **Technical remark:** $$
f(x)=\frac{x+1}{x^2-1} \ne \frac{1}{x-1}
$$
since the LHS is not defined at $x = -1$ and the RHS is. The intuition here is right but you have to restrict $x$ to be in a neighborhood of $1$ to avoid this problem.

Comment: Let me fix that @Théophile

Comment: Edited... @Théophile can you help me understand the intuition of this?

Comment: Your edit makes more sense, but a couple more things need to be fixed. First, do you mean to give the definition for $\lim_{x\to c}f(x) = \infty$? Second, although not strictly necessary, it would be clearer to use either $N$ or $L$ throughout. (You have $N$ in the definition and $L$ in the proof.)

Comment: Yes, can you help me understand where the $\frac{1}{L+\epsilon}$ comes from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the definition as directly as possible will help your proof.

> $\lim_{x\to c}f(x) = \infty$  means $ \forall N>0:\exists \delta :0<|x-c|<\delta \implies f(x)>N$.

Let me work with the function $g(x) = \frac1{|x-1|}$ for now; we'll prove that $\lim_{x\to1}g(x) = \infty$.

So, take any $N > 0$. Our goal is to find a $\delta$ such that if $0 < |x-1| < \delta$, then $g(x) > N$. Note that by taking reciprocals of the inequality $|x-1| < \delta$, we get
$$\frac1{|x-1|}>\frac1\delta.$$
The left-hand side is $g(x)$, so we're almost done. We just need to find a $\delta$ that works; in this case, pick any $\delta < \frac1N$, for then
$$g(x)=\frac1{|x-1|}>\frac1\delta>N.$$

This gives you almost everything you need to prove the limit for your function $f(x)$.